# Validate phone number in contact form

Tags: php, contact-form

I have this form [Link](http://dh-creative-webdesign.de/das-bauteam/kontakt.php)
The validation should validate if a valid phone number is entered and if not then
give the error text "Bitte geben Sie eine gültige Telefonnummer an", but the validation gives always the same message "Bitte geben Sie Ihre Telefonnummer an" in english please type in your phone number even if you enter invalid characters.

PHP:

```
function setParams($post)
{
    if ( ! $this->name = strip_tags(trim($post['name'])))
    {
        $this->error[] = 'Bitte geben Sie Ihren Namen an.';
    }
    if ( ! $this->phone = strip_tags(trim($post['phone'])))
    {
        $this->error[] = 'Bitte geben Sie Ihre Telefonnummer an.';
    } else if ( preg_match('#[^0-9\+\-\040/]#', $phone) )
    {
        $this->error[] = 'Bitte geben Sie eine gültige Telefonnummer an.';
    }   

    if ( ! $this->email = strip_tags(trim($post['email'])))
    {
        $this->error[] = 'Bitte geben Sie Ihre E-Mail-Adresse an.';
    } else if ( ! filter_var($this->email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) || strstr($this->email, '@') === FALSE)
    {
        $this->error[] = 'Bitte geben Sie eine gültige E-Mail-Adresse an.';
    }
    if ( ! $this->body = strip_tags(trim($post['message'])))
    {
        $this->error[] = 'Bitte geben Sie einen Nachrichtentext ein.';
    }
```

HTML:

```
<form action="kontakt.php" method="post">
            <label for="name">Ihr Name:</label><input class="get1" type="text"     name="name" value="" /><br />
            <label for="telefon">Telefonnummer (bitte nur Ziffern):</label><input     class="get1" type="text" name="phone" value="" /><br />
            <label for="email">E-Mail-Adresse:</label><input class="get1" type="text"     name="email" value="" /><br />
            <label for="message">Ihre Mitteilung an uns:</label><textarea cols="20"     rows="5" name="message"></textarea><br />
            <label>Welche Leistungen interessieren Sie besonders?    </label>
            <label style="display:inline;" for="dachstuehle">Dachstühle</label>  <input     class="kaestchen" type="checkbox" name="interessen[]" id="dachstuehle" value="dachstuehle"     />
            <label style="display:inline;" for="holzbau">Holzbau</label>         <input class="kaestchen" type="checkbox" name="interessen[]" id="holzbau" value="holzbau" />
            <label style="display:inline;" for="innenausbau">Innenausbau</label> <input class="kaestchen" type="checkbox" name="interessen[]" id="innenausbau" value="innenausbau" />
            <label style="display:inline;" for="trocken">Trockenbau</label>      <input class="kaestchen" type="checkbox" name="interessen[]" id="trockenbau" value="trockenbau" /><br /><br />
            <input type="hidden" value="1" name="s" />
            <input type="submit" value="Nachricht versenden" name="submit" />
            </form>
```

What is wrong?

Comment: I take the easy way out. I put fields on the form for each part of a phone number and then validate each chunk. Trying to create a regex for dashes, dots and parentheses it annoying.

Comment: thats not solving a problem, its avoiding

Comment: Shouldn't be `if(!preg_match` ? You're erroring a likely correct number

Comment: Don't validate phone numbers. It's the most horribly annoying thing in contact forms ever. What if my phone number is from another country? What if it's super long? What if I don't want to enter one?

Comment: OP: What have you tried to fixed the issue by yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the reason you're getting `'Bitte geben Sie Ihre Telefonnummer an.'` is because `$post['phone'];` is empty or false or becomes empty/false after it's trimmed and the tags are stripped.  Try echo'ing out `$post['phone']` right before the if statement to see what it says. You may have an minor issue where your form is posting `telephone` even though you're checking for `phone`.

In addition to the `$post['phone']` being empty you have an error on the preg match line. You're doing `$phone` when you need to do `$this->phone`:

```
} else if ( preg_match('#[^0-9\+\-\040/]#', $this->phone) )
```